# Access IoT Edge Device Twin from Edge Module when using X.509 Authentication

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Scenario:

IoT Edge Gateway provisioned using DPS & X.509 Authentication
Leaf devices will use SAS key and will each have their own identity in IoT Hub

We need to access Edge Device Twin properties from an IoT Edge module.
This would be possible if we used SAS authentication and had the connection string readily available, but we do not because Edge is provisioned and authenticated using X.509
How can we achieve this please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing device twin from an IoT Edge module is not supported or recommended.

*(Edit adding some more detail as to why)*:

IoT Edge's security/isolation model does not allow modules to access device-level twin by design as the operation needs higher elevation creds that modules don’t/shouldn’t have.

Comment: So how would you tell if a device level attribute changed from within a module. For example, if the car state is driving=true, how does the seatbelt module know that the car is driving so it can make that annoying beeping sound?